# How to query a table efficiently without affecting live transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a high transaction table with millions of records with the structure below:

```
transaction
--------------
id             int
txn_status     varchar
amount         bigint
name           varchar
txn_time       datetime --Date and time of the transaction
```

The `txn_status` field value can be `completed` or `Pending`. I need to run a query that will retrieve the number of records with the following characteristics:

1. Transactions with `Pending txn_status` since the last 15 minutes i.e `(current_time - txn_time) <= 15 minutes`
2. Transactions with `Pending txn_status` between the last 16 and 25 minutes i.e `(current_time - txn_time) >= 16 minutes and (current_time - txn_time) <= 25 minutes`
3. Transactions with `Pending txn_status` between the last 26 and 30 minutes i.e `(current_time - txn_time) >= 26 minutes and (current_time - txn_time) <= 30 minutes`
4. Transactions with `Pending txn_status` more than 30 minutes i.e `(current_time - txn_time) > 30 minutes`

There are two solutions currently in my head currently:

1. Query the production database every minute using a `case` statement (the case statement will filter and group the records based on the time difference above) in the `where` clause of the query.
2. To avoid putting much load on the production database, have a separate database with a similar table and have an `update` and `insert` triggers update the table and execute the query in No. 1 above afterwards on the database.

Please if there is any optimal or better solution in achieving this without putting much load on the database, please share.

Comment: I'm not enough of an expert to write this as a full answer, but the first thing I'd try to speed things up is to make txn_status an integer field, and add an index to it.  You generally don't want to do a string comparison on millions of records.

Comment: @Dave That is correct and I will do the same but this is a legacy database, you know how it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an index of the form

```
CREATE INDEX txn_status_time ON transaction (txn_status, txn_time DESC)
```

and write the query in a way that compares to txn_time without arithmetic, then your query will be shockingly fast

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), 
    CASE WHEN txn_time >= current_time - 15 mins THEN "last 15" ... END
FROM transaction
GROUP BY CASE WHEN txn_time >= current_time - 15 mins THEN "last 15" ... END
```

Answer (score 2):

The first solution shouldn't put much load on the database if you have proper indexes i.e. a composite index `INDEX(txn_status, txn_time)`

If most of the rows in your table are not pending, queries like this should be very fast: `SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE txn_status = 'pending' AND txn_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE` as the number of non-pending rows shouldn't really affect the speed of the query at all.

Comment: A minute faster than me, exactly what I suggested, +1

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - the best solution is often the simplest. See if you can execute your queries on the production database without undue performance pain; tune those queries by adding indexes. "Millions of records" isn't a big deal as long as you have good indexes and queries that hit those indexes.

I recommend against option 2. I'm generally opposed to using triggers in this way, because they can lead to unpredictable behaviour, including unpredictable performance issues. If your "update" trigger starts to run slowly, it will also affect your production database; all it would take is for a developer to drop an index on your reporting database by accident and your production system could slow down and become unusable.

Instead, consider [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) - it sorts out the plumbing of moving data around, and is generally much more performance-friendly.